# Monit's second "Does not exist" overrides first one

Tags: monitoring, monit

I have a process which I am monitoring using Monit. If process dies for some reason, I want to send a Slack notification using a shell script and also restart it. This behaviour though does not work with "does not exist" directive. The last one is executed and previous one ignored. For example code below:

```
check process xyz with pidfile /var/run/xyz.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/xyz start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/xyz stop"
  if does not exist then restart
  if does not exist then exec "/opt/somescript.sh"
```

It executes script but does not restart. it also looks like from documentation that this is how it will behave. Any other way to get this working. Documentation reference (Not exactly clear but resembles the actual behaviour):

```
If not defined, it defaults to a restart action.
You can override the default action with the following statement:
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the default action is already to restart the process, as per the documentation, and you are overriding that with an `exec` action

Cleaner way is to add the restart script inside your `somescript.sh`.

If you don't want to do that, you can also combine the two actions in one, like this:

```
if does not exist then exec "/etc/init.d/xyz restart && /opt/somescript.sh"
```

Comment: Sorry but that's just typo from my side while typing the question, corrected now

Comment: Oh I see. I updated the answer, probably best to put the restart and the script into 1 action instead.

Comment: for some strange reason even if I call two commands in exec, separated by && - it calls only the first one. I tested this by changing the places but always only one command is called!

Answer (score 0):

I believe monit doesn't allow you to have the same statements twice. You would have to write your script on restarting the process in your `somescript.sh`.